# Why are weights not regulated?

Tags: rigify

I created a rig, then I tried to adjust the weights, but it does not work as I would expect. Why the weights are not regulated?

Painting some weights...

[image: screenshot 1]

... painting more - but it has no effect.

[image: screenshot 2]

Here is the complete video of what is happening...
https://youtu.be/tl7psX9eZlw

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have selected the wrong vertex group.** Each bone has a vertex group with the same name. But *thigh.L* is not a deformation bone of Rigify's animation rig (the one called *rig*). The deformation bones in this rig all have a *DEF-* prefix, so all their names start with *DEF-*.

You need to look for bones named *DEF-thigh.L* and *DEF-thigh.L.001*. There are two bones because Rigify creates two twist bones in the animation rig by default.

[image: screenshot 1]

My guess is that the *thigh.L* bone is from the *metarig* and you accidentally bound the mesh to it. The *Parent To > ...* operation creates the vertex groups. You can delete them by locking all *DEF-* groups and those you want to keep, then select *Delete All Unlocked Groups* from the drop-down menu. Don't forget to unlock the bones again for weight painting.

Check the mesh and make sure you only have one *Armature* modifier on the mesh and that it's the correct one.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: thank you very much for your response.